# Get the part after the decimal in a float

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to "split" a float so I get the value **before** the decimal mark and the value **after** the decimal mark?

```
float myVal = 1.234;
// how to get .234 and 1
```

I saw another example but it's in Java and I can't figure out how to do this in objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/modf/) function:

```
float intPart = 0;
float fractPart = modf(myVal, &intPart);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <math.h>


float myVal = 1.234f;

int wholePart = (int)myVal;
float fractionalPart = fmodf(myVal, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int   wholePart = (int) myVal;
float fractionalPart = myVal - wholePart;
```

I am sure ther are lots of functions in math.h that you coud abuse for that too.

Comment: This may not work for all inputs - conversion from float to int may be lossy, and may not convert back to float as the exact same value.